# Definition of Poincaré rank

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

Dealing with the *confluent Heun equation*, something unimportant to me at the beginning got me curious lately: the *Poincaré rank* of an irregular singularity.

In particular, that one in the confluent Heun equation at the point $\infty$ is $1$.

I have tried to find the definition of this rank, but its origin seems to be in a paper written in German, which I can't read. Also I have found different definitions in other texts that depend on the context I guess.

So my question is, for the people working in the field of ODEs and special functions, **is there a standard/generally accepted definition of the Poincaré rank?**

Just for the record, the one that I was assuming to be 'correct' is the following:

We say that the function $F(z)$ has rank $r$ at an *irregular singularity* $z_i$ (for $z_i$ a complex value, not $\infty$) if it can be written as
$$(z-z_i)^{-r-1}F_0(z),$$
where $F_0(z)$ has a convergent Taylor series expansion in some neighborhood containing $z_i$.

If $F$ has rank $r\geq 1$ at $z=\infty$, there exists $F_0(z)$ such that
$$F(z)=z^{r-1}F_0(z),$$
where $F_0(z)$ has a convergent Taylor series expansion in $z^{-1}$ around $\infty$ and $F_0(\infty)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following discussion can be found in the book *Heun's Differential Equations* edited by A. Ronveaux.

Suppose that $z=\infty$ is an *irregular singularity* of the ODE
\begin{equation}
 y^{\prime\prime}(z)+p(z)y^{\prime}(z)+q(z)y(z)=0
\end{equation}
with $p$ and $q$ rational functions and that, as $z\to\infty$,
\begin{equation}
 p(z)=\mathcal{O}\left(z^{k_1}\right),\quad q(z)=\mathcal{O}\left(z^{k_2}\right).
\end{equation}

Since $p$ and $q$ are rational functions, $k_1$ and $k_2$ are integers, and in the case of one of them being identically zero, we take the corresponding $k_i$ as $-\infty$. Defining
\begin{equation}
 g:=\max\left(k_1,\frac{k_2}{2}\right),
\end{equation}
the *Poincaré rank* is defined by
\begin{equation}
 h:=g+1.
\end{equation}